# Standard for "not found" when using size_t

Tags: clang, size-t

Is there a standard what value to use when you do an array search and the value is not found.
With signed I would return -1. But what about size_t aka long unsigned.

```
   int find(int a[],int b, int n){
   for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
       if(a[i]==b)
           return i;
   }
   return -1;
   }
```

When using size_t just would come up with this. But it's not really perfect.

```
   long long int find(int a[],int b, size_t n){
   for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++){
       if(a[i]==b)
           return (long long int)i;
   }
   return -1;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow a size_t type to have a negative value, there is a `ssize_t` type which is signed.

You can't rely on the equivalence of the size_t to unsigned long as its architecture specific.